# Looking for the correct statistical assay

Tags: regression, time-series, anova, dataset

I am currently looking for the correct way to analyze my data.
The experimental set-up consists of drug-treatment vs control over time. So I have three conditions: Control, Drug 1, and Drug 2. For each drug I tested expression of Genes at discrete time points equally apart. Like day 1, 2, 4, and 5. (I'll attach a dummy sample below)

In the beginning, I fitted a linear model for each gene in order to find the genes in my control, where expression is best explained by time. I would now like to compare if and how expression over time changes between by conditions (Control vs Drug1). If there is a significant change in Gen A, B, C... expression over time and wether the correlation with time increases or decreases between them (if they are getting up-regulated or down-regulated).

Does anyone have any suggestions, please?

Thank you

#Dataframe : Control
Days : 1,  2,  3,  4,  5
Gen A: 2,  4,  6,  8, 10
Gen B: 9, 10, 11, 14, 18
...

#Dataframe : Drug 1
Days : 1,  2,  3,  4,  5
Gen A: 3,  7,  11,  17, 22
Gen B: 6,  6,  6,    1,  1
...

Comment: anyone please :(

Comment: Can you give us more details on this condition? It sounds like you want to test for a difference in means between the two samples. Is it relevant which day each measurement was taken?

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your answer. I edited my original post to include more information and to better explain my set-up and goals.